# In Vulkan, is it beneficial for the graphics queue family to be separate from the present queue family?

Tags: c++, vulkan

As far as I can tell it is possible for a queue family to support presenting to the screen but not support graphics. Say I have a queue family that supports both graphics and presenting, and another queue family that only supports presenting. Should I use the first queue family for both processes or should I delegate the first to graphics and the latter to presenting? Or would there be no noticeable difference between these two approaches?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No such HW exists, so best approach is no approach. If you want to be really nice, you can handle the separate present queue family case with expending minimal brain-power on it. Though you have no way to test it on real HW that needs it. So I would say abort with a nice error message would be as adequate, until you can get your hands on actual HW that does it.

I think there is bit of a design error here on Khronoses part. Separate present queue does look like a more explicit way. But then, present op itself is not a queue operation, so the driver can use whatever it wants anyway. Also separate present requires extra semaphore, and Queue Family Ownership Transfer (or `VK_SHARING_MODE_CONCURRENT` resource). The history went the way that no driver is so extremist to report a separate present queue. So I made [KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Docs#1234](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Docs/issues/1234).

For rough notion of what happens at `vkQueuePresentKHR`, you can inspect Mesa code: https://github.com/mesa3d/mesa/blob/bf3c9d27706dc2362b81aad12eec1f7e48e53ddd/src/vulkan/wsi/wsi_common.c#L1120-L1232. There's probably no monkey business there using the queue you provided except waiting on your semaphore, or at most making a blit of the image. If you (voluntarily) want to use separate present queue, you need to measure and whitelist it only for drivers (and probably other influences) it actually helps (if any such exist, and if it is even worth your time).

Comment: Maybe this wasn't true in Apr. 2020, but as of now there is hardware/drivers out there that support presentation on the compute queue, so it's not exactly a speculative question (see e.g. https://gpuopen.com/performance/#presenting ; my NVIDIA card is like this too). As far as I can tell, the graphics queue basically always supports presentation if the hardware supports it at all in general, so the question then becomes whether or not it's worth it to present on the compute queue instead of the graphics queue and under what circumstances.

Comment: @ZoëSparks As far as I know there is still no HW that exposes present-only queues. Mostly because it is little bit nonsensical to do so on API design level.

Comment: This answer is very useful. Very often, when reading the specs, it's hard to tell how the abstractions map into real HW. In this case, there isn't even any HW that uses this abstraction...

Comment: My phone has a queue family only support present and spase binding: https://vulkan.gpuinfo.org/displayreport.php?id=18342#queuefamilies, does it means it actually is a queue family only for spase binding?

Comment: @zzy It just means all queue families on Android automatically support present. I don't think one can create sparse swapchain images, so yea, I don't see much point in presenting on this queue, but it should work.

Answer (score 3):

First off, I assume you mean "beneficial" in terms of performance, and whenever it comes to questions like that you can never have a definite answer except by profiling the different strategies. If your application needs to run on a variety of hardware, you can have it profile the different strategies the first time it's run and save the results locally for repeated use, provide the user with a benchmarking utility they can run if they see poor performance, etc. etc. Trying to reason about it in the abstract can only get you so far.

That aside, I think the easiest way to think about questions like this is to remember that when it comes to graphics programming, you want to both maximize the amount of work that can be done in parallel and minimize the amount of work overall. If you want to present an image from a non-graphics queue and you need to perform graphics operations on it, you'll need to transfer ownership of it to the non-graphics queue when graphics operations on it have finished. Presumably, that will take a bit of time in the driver if nothing else, so it's only worth doing if it will save you time elsewhere somehow.

A common situation where this *would* probably save you time is if the device supports async compute and also lets you present from the compute queue. For example, a 3D game might use the compute queue for things like lighting, blur, UI, etc. that make the most sense to do after geometry processing is finished. In this case, the game engine would transfer ownership of the image to be presented to the compute queue first anyway, or even have the compute queue own the swapchain image from beginning to end, so presenting from the compute queue once its work for the frame is done would allow the graphics queue to stay busy with the next frame. [AMD](https://gpuopen.com/performance/#presenting) and [NVIDIA](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/advanced-api-performance-async-compute-and-overlap/) recommend this sort of approach where it's possible.

If your application wouldn't otherwise use the compute queue, though, I'm not sure how much sense it makes or not to present on it when you have the option. The advantage of that approach is that once graphics operations for a given frame are over, you can have the graphics queue immediately release ownership of the image for it and acquire the next one without having to pause to present it, which would allow presentation to be done in parallel with rendering the next frame. On the other hand, you'll have to transfer ownership of it to the compute queue first and set up presentation there, which would add some complexity and overhead. I'm not sure which approach would be faster and I wouldn't be surprised if it varies with the application and environment. Of course, I'm not sure how many realtime Vulkan applications of any significant complexity fit this scenario today, and I'd guess it's not very many as "per-pixel" things tend to be easier and faster to do with a compute shader.